# Set state attribute for request object in fastapi/starlette test client

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, starlette

I have a GET endpoint that proxies another endpoint and it expects to extract Bearer token from request's state attribute. This is my endpoint

```
from fastapi import Depends, Request
from starlette.requests import Request
from starlette.status import HTTP_200_OK
from starlette.testclient import TestClient


@router.get("/", response_model=DataOut)
def get_documents(request: Request, query_params: QueryParams = Depends()) -> DataOut:
    return DocumentsOut.parse_obj(
        data_api_client.get(
            "/data/",
            request.state.token,
            params=query_params.dict(by_alias=True),
        ).json()
    )
```

Now I want to have integration test for it. I have test client. However I'm not able to set request state attribute in test client. How can I solve this problem? Below is my test function

```
def test_get_data(my_test_client: TestClient, api_url: str, api_token: str) -> None:
    params = {
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 20,
    }
    response = my_test_client.get(url=api_url, headers={"Authorization": api_token}, params=params)
    assert response.status_code == HTTP_200_OK
```

When I debug this test and arrive at the endpoint, the state attribute of the request object is empty.

Comment: The whole stack - including where you're populating `.token` in stack should still be the same, so what does your middleware where you're populating `token` look like?